# Wordpress Hook that will run when media file deleted

Tags: plugins, php, hooks

I am very new in wordpress and I am currently developing a wordpress plugin, I just want to know if there is a wordpress plugin hook that will run when one or more file of wordpress media is deleted.

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`delete_attachment`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/delete_attachment/) action is fired when [`wp_delete_attachment()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_attachment/) function is called to delete an item in the media library.

Comment: i already got the snippets  but still your answer is correct. thanks by the way

Comment: Regarding `https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/delete_attachment/`, it fires before an attachment is deleted, at the start of wp_delete_attachment(). So it is risky if you delete the file but WordPress doesn't due to an error or something.